Expected Number and Variance of Active Node Pairs in a Rectangular Grid Network
I aim to count the number of pairs of active nodes, denoted as $X$, on a network structured as a regular rectangular grid, either with or without periodic boundary conditions. Specifically, consider an $M\times N$ grid where exactly $A$ nodes are active. What is the expected number of active pairs $X$, and what is the variance of $X$?
Numerical exploration suggests that $X$ follows a distribution resembling the hypergeometric distribution. Naively, the probability of forming a pair is $p=\frac{A}{M N}\cdot\frac{A-1}{M N - 1}$. Then the mean should be $\langle X \rangle = 2 M N p = \frac{2 A (A-1)}{M N - 1}$ (numerical simulations confirm this). However, the variance is smaller than what would be expected for a binomial random variable. Reduction in variance suggests similarity to the hypergeometric distribution. But this does not help me determine a general expression for the factor by which the variance is reduced. Any suggestions on how to approach this issue?
-Edit- Clarification: Locations of the active nodes are selected at random, but there are always exactly $A$ nodes active.

You don’t state it, but I’m assuming the active nodes are selected at random?  In which case, your derivation of $E[X]$ (with periodic b.c.) is correct (not naive), and you just need to find $E[X^2]$ to get the variance.  Can you see how to do that?

Yes, the nodes (locations of the active nodes on the grid) are selected at random. Yet, I have no idea how to obtain $E[X^2]$.

Would writing $X$ as sum of indicator variables of all pairs be helpful? Then to find $\mathbb E [X^2]$ by linearity you just need to find $\mathbb E [IJ]$ and there are two types of those: those whore share a vertex and those who don't.

Let $\rho_k$ be the probability that any particular set of $k$ distinct nodes are all active.  In your case, you have
$$
\rho_1 = \frac{A}{MN}, \;\;
\rho_2=\frac{A(A-1)}{MN(MN-1)}, \;\;
\rho_3=\frac{A(A-1)(A-2)}{MN(MN-1)(MN-2)},
$$
and so on.  The total number of active pairs is $X=\sum_{e} N_{e}$, where $e$ is summed over all the edges (there are $2MN$ of them in the periodic boundary case), and $N_e$ is $1$ if both ends of an edge are active and $0$ otherwise.  So
$$
E[X]=\sum_e E[N_e]=2MN \cdot E[N_a] = 2MN \rho_2=\frac{2A(A-1)}{MN-1},
$$
where $a$ is any particular edge, since all edges have the same probability ($\rho_2$) of spanning an active pair.  Now note that
$$
E[X^2]=\sum_e \sum_f E[N_e N_f] = 2MN \sum_f E[N_a N_f].
$$
If $f=a$ (one term in the sum), then $E[N_a N_f]=\rho_2$; if $f$ shares exactly one node with $a$ (which can happen in $6$ ways), then $E[N_a N_f]=\rho_3$; and if $f$ and $a$ are completely disjoint (all remaining terms), then $E[N_a N_f]=\rho_4$.  So
$$
E[X^2]=2MN\left(\rho_2 + 6\rho_3 + (2MN-7)\rho_4\right).
$$
This leaves the variance as
$$
{\text{Var}}[X] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2=2MN\rho_2+12MN\rho_3-14MN\rho_4+4M^2N^2\left(\rho_4 - \rho_2^2 \right) = E[X]\left(1 + 6\frac{\rho_3}{\rho_2} - 7\frac{\rho_4}{\rho_2} + 2MN\left(\frac{\rho_4}{\rho_2}-\rho_2\right)\right).
$$

Note that if each node were active independently with fixed probability $\rho$, then $\rho_k = \rho^k$, and you have the much simpler result for the variance, $E[X](1 + 6\rho - 7\rho^2)=EX(1-\rho)$.
